# Remove rootkit from Windows XP Pro system

Tags: windows

How can I best detect AND remove rootkits from my Windows XP Pro system

Answer (score 2):

**To Detect**

[Rootkit revealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx)

**To remove**

1. Backup your data (file based backup, not an image backup)
2. Obliterate and re-create the partitions and filesystem
3. re-install your system.
4. Install Virus Scanner (with up to date defs)
5. Restore your data

You could spend weeks trying to remove a rootkit, and you could never be 100% certain that it has gone. The only guaranteed way to do it, is wipe and start again.

Comment: +1 for the equivelant of "nuke the site from orbit, it's the only way to be sure"

Answer (score 1):

[GMER](http://www.gmer.net/) is the more powerfull one, but it's not user friendly

[Avira Anti Rootkit](http://www.free-av.com/en/products/4/avira_antirootkit_tool.html) & [Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/avptool2010?level=2) are more user friendly and almost as powerfull